# Error con Login y Signup en python

Tags: python, json

Tengo un problema con un código de IMC. Es una tarea para la universidad, y ya logra que haga login, y sign up... Sin embargo si no se cumple ninguna de estas dos, el código no funciona.

```
import json


def proceso():
    opcion = input("(1) Sign up (usuario nuevo) o (2) Login (usuario ya existente)")
    if opcion == "1" or opcion == "Sign up" or opcion == "sign up" or opcion == "Sign Up":
        usuario = input("Ingrese su usuario:")
        password = input("Ingrese su contraseña:")
    elif opcion == "2" or opcion == "log in" or opcion == "Log In" or opcion == "Login":
        print("Ok, porfavor continua a Login.")
        print("Warning: Si no ingresa correctamente su ususario y contraseña, no se podran guardar los datos en su usuario.")
        usuario = input("Ingrese su usuario:")
        password = input("Ingrese su contraseña:")
        with open('data.txt') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for entity in data['datos']:
                entityname = entity["user"]
                entitypassword = entity["password"]
            if entityname == usuario and entitypassword == password:
                print("Usuario encontrado. ", "Bienvenido, ", usuario)
            else:
                print("Usuario y contraseña no encontrados.")
                print("No se guardaran los datos ingresados")
                print("Le recomendamos volver a correr el codigo, por si ingreso mal su usuario y/o contraseña")
    else:
        print("Atencion: Los datos no se guardaran")

    edad = float(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
    if edad <= 17:
        print ("Por ser menor de edad los datos pueden no ser exactos. Le recomendamos que para algo mas exacto, consulte a un professional.")
    else:
        print ("Por ser mayor de edad los datos seran mas exactos, sin embargo siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")

    sexo = input("Ingrese su sexo. (M) Masculino o (F) Femenino.")
    while sexo == "M" or sexo == "F" or sexo == "m" or sexo == "f":
        print ("El IMC puede variar dependiendo de su sexo.")
        print("El IMC dado en este programa es un estimado. Siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")
        break
    else:
        print("Por favor ingrese una opcion valida.")
        sexo = input("Ingrese su sexo. (M) Masculino o (F) Femenino.")
        while sexo == "M" or sexo == "F" or sexo == "m" or sexo == "f":
            print("El IMC puede variar dependiendo de su sexo.")
            print("El IMC dado en este programa es un estimado. Siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")
            break
        else:
            print("Bien, como quieras. Si no quieres decir tu genero no importa...")

    pesokg = float(input("Ingrese su peso en kilogramos (kg) o ponga cero (0) si sabe su peso en libras (lb). "))
    if pesokg == 0:
        pesolb = float(input("Ingrese su peso en libras (lb)."))
        pesokg = pesolb/2.205
    print("Su peso es de, ", pesokg, " kg.")
    estaturam = float(input("Ingrese su estatura en (m) metros. O ponga (0) cero para ingresarlo en (ft) pies "))
    if estaturam == 0:
        estaturaft = float(input("Ingrese su estatura en (ft) pies."))
        estaturam = estaturaft/3.281
    print("Su estatura es de, ", estaturam, " m.")
    imc = pesokg / estaturam**2
    print("Se IMC es de, ", imc)
    print("¿No sabes lo que esto significa?")
    print("No te preocupes, nosotros nos encargamos de los numeros para que tu no lo tengas que hacer. ;)")
    if imc <= 18.4:
        print("Su peso es muy bajo. Tienes que comer mejor.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Subida de peso (1)")
    elif imc >= 18.5 and imc <= 24.9:
        print("Su peso es normal. ¡¡¡Felicidades!!!")
        print("Plan a seguir: Mantener peso (2)")
    elif imc >= 25 and imc <= 29.9:
        print("Su peso es demasiado. Usted esta en sobrepeso, deberia de adelgazar.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Bajar de peso (3)")
    else:
        print("Usted esta obeso. Tiene que comer menos y mas saludable.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Bajar de peso urgente (4)")
    print("No se preocupe. No importando su estado actual, nosotros le ayudaremos a mejorar su condicion o mantenerla si ya esta bien.")

    import datetime
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    datestr = str(date)

    data = {}
    data['datos'] = []
    data['datos'].append({
        "user": usuario,
        "password": password,
        "edad": edad,
        "sexo": sexo,
        "pesokg": pesokg,
        "estatura": estaturam,
        "imc": imc,
        "date": datestr
    })

    with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
proceso()
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es simplemente que ejecutas la parte final del código (donde guardas los datos del usuario) en todos los casos, también cuando el usuario ni se registra ni se identifica. En este supuesto, las variables `usuario` y `password` no existen ya que se definen en los bloques bajo el `if` y el `elif` pero no en el `else`. Esto hace que al intentar referenciarlas en la creación del diccionario `data` tengas un error del tipo:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment

ya que intentas usar variables que no existen.

Una solución muy simple sin apenas modificar tu código es usar una variable boleana que permita solo guardar si se cumple el `if` o el `elif`, pero no el `else`:

```
import datetime
import json



def proceso():
    guardar = True
    opcion = input("(1) Sign up (usuario nuevo) o (2) Login (usuario ya existente)").lower()
    if opcion == "1" or opcion == "sign up":
        usuario = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")
        password = input("Ingrese su contraseña: ")

    elif opcion == "2" or opcion == "log in":
        print("Ok, porfavor continua a Login.")
        print("Warning: Si no ingresa correctamente su ususario y contraseña, no se podran guardar los datos en su usuario.")
        usuario = input("Ingrese su usuario:")
        password = input("Ingrese su contraseña:")
        with open('data.txt') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for entity in data['datos']:
                entityname = entity["user"]
                entitypassword = entity["password"]
            if entityname == usuario and entitypassword == password:
                print("Usuario encontrado. ", "Bienvenido, ", usuario)
            else:
                print("Usuario y contraseña no encontrados.")
                print("No se guardaran los datos ingresados")
                print("Le recomendamos volver a correr el codigo, por si ingreso mal su usuario y/o contraseña")
    else:
        guardar = False
        print("Atencion: Los datos no se guardaran")

    edad = float(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
    if edad <= 17:
        print ("Por ser menor de edad los datos pueden no ser exactos. Le recomendamos que para algo mas exacto, consulte a un professional.")
    else:
        print ("Por ser mayor de edad los datos seran mas exactos, sin embargo siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")

    sexo = input("Ingrese su sexo. (M) Masculino o (F) Femenino.").lower()
    while sexo == "m" or sexo == "f":
        print ("El IMC puede variar dependiendo de su sexo.")
        print("El IMC dado en este programa es un estimado. Siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")
        break
    else:
        print("Por favor ingrese una opcion valida.")
        sexo = input("Ingrese su sexo. (M) Masculino o (F) Femenino.").lower()
        while sexo ==  "m" or sexo == "f":
            print("El IMC puede variar dependiendo de su sexo.")
            print("El IMC dado en este programa es un estimado. Siempre es mejor consultar con un professional.")
            break
        else:
            print("Bien, como quieras. Si no quieres decir tu genero no importa...")

    pesokg = float(input("Ingrese su peso en kilogramos (kg) o ponga cero (0) si sabe su peso en libras (lb). "))
    if pesokg == 0:
        pesolb = float(input("Ingrese su peso en libras (lb)."))
        pesokg = pesolb/2.205
    print("Su peso es de, ", pesokg, " kg.")
    estaturam = float(input("Ingrese su estatura en (m) metros. O ponga (0) cero para ingresarlo en (ft) pies "))
    if estaturam == 0:
        estaturaft = float(input("Ingrese su estatura en (ft) pies."))
        estaturam = estaturaft/3.281
    print("Su estatura es de, ", estaturam, " m.")
    imc = pesokg / estaturam**2
    print("Se IMC es de, ", imc)
    print("¿No sabes lo que esto significa?")
    print("No te preocupes, nosotros nos encargamos de los numeros para que tu no lo tengas que hacer. ;)")
    if imc <= 18.4:
        print("Su peso es muy bajo. Tienes que comer mejor.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Subida de peso (1)")
    elif imc >= 18.5 and imc <= 24.9:
        print("Su peso es normal. ¡¡¡Felicidades!!!")
        print("Plan a seguir: Mantener peso (2)")
    elif imc >= 25 and imc <= 29.9:
        print("Su peso es demasiado. Usted esta en sobrepeso, deberia de adelgazar.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Bajar de peso (3)")
    else:
        print("Usted esta obeso. Tiene que comer menos y mas saludable.")
        print("Plan a seguir: Bajar de peso urgente (4)")
    print("No se preocupe. No importando su estado actual, nosotros le ayudaremos a mejorar su condicion o mantenerla si ya esta bien.")


    if guardar:
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        datestr = str(date)

        data = {}
        data['datos'] = []
        data['datos'].append({
            "user": usuario,
            "password": password,
            "edad": edad,
            "sexo": sexo,
            "pesokg": pesokg,
            "estatura": estaturam,
            "imc": imc,
            "date": datestr
        })

        with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)

proceso()
```

De cualquier forma, te recomendaría dividir tu función en funciones más pequeñas que solo hagan una cosa (guardar datos, login, sigs up, cáculo del IMC, etc).